# "./ngrok authtoken <my_authtoken>" not working

Tags: ngrok, kali-linux

I've got kali linux from microsoft store.

I wanted to run `./ngrok authtoken <my_authtoken>`

but got `-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

so I tried `chmod +x ./ngrok authtoken <my_authtoken>` and `sudo chmod +x ./ngrok authtoken <my_authtoken>`

but either way I get `chmod: cannot access 'authtoken': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access '<my_authtoken>'`

what should I do?
I really need to run `./ngrok authtoken <my_authtoken>`

P.S: I want to use blackeye and when I chose the number it downloaded Ngrok

edit 1: I downloaded another version from https://ngrok.com/download and I removed the previous Ngrok in blackeye directory and unziped the new one instead.
now I'm getting `bash: ./ngrok: Permission denied`

edit 2: It's been 12 days with no accurate answer guess I gotta get the real Kali Linux and the problem is the windows version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always Google and try to find an answer before you post a question.

Your first error (`-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`) is probably because your trying to run a program made for a different architecture such as x86 or ARM (see https://askubuntu.com/a/648558).

Your second error (`chmod: cannot access 'authtoken': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access '<my_authtoken>'`) is because your trying to run a command from within chmod, you have to chmod the file then run it.

Your third error (`bash: ./ngrok: Permission denied`) is because you need to chmod the file to an executable before you can run it, and there is no need for sudo unless chmod returns `chmod: cannot access '<yourfile>': Permission denied` then you should use sudo.

What your should run is:

```
curl -L https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip -o ngrok.zip
unzip ngrok.zip
chmod +x ngrok
./ngrok authtoken <myauthtoken>
```

Comment: thank you but it didn't work still gives me the "-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" and I had searched but like what you answered they don't work and like I said before I know it's not the version I need so I downloaded other versions but still they weren't the one. please read the questions carefully.

Comment: Side note: Use ARM version of Ngrok if building for Nvidia Jetson :-)

Answer (score 0):

this was the only thing that work for me:

```
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null && echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list && sudo apt update && sudo apt install ngrok
```